# remainder when 67896789...(300 digits) divided by 999

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

What is the remainder when 678967896789... (300 digits)is divided by 999?
i tried to divide it manually to find some pattern in remainder. But was getting bit lengthy. 
so please suggest me some short method.

Comment: The number is $$6789\sum_{i=0}^{74} 10^{4i}$$

Comment: Do you know how to use modular arithmetic?

Answer (score 4):

Similar to [casting out nines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_out_nines) to find the remainder when divided by 9, you can cast out 999's to find the remainder when divided by 999. The reason this works is the same: 1000 = 1 modulo 999, so xyz000...000 = xyz modulo 999. But instead of just adding up the digits, you have to add three-digit groups.

Take for instance the number 12345678. Break this into three-digit groups (starting from the right):

12 345 678

Take the sum:

12 + 345 + 678 = 1035

Reduce modulo 999, using the same trick:

1035 = 1 + 035 = 36 mod 999

So 12345678 = 36 mod 999.

In your case, we have

678 967 896 789

repeated 25 times:

25 * (678 + 967 + 896 + 789) = 25 * 3330 = 83250

So 67896789...6789 = 83250 = 83 + 250 = 333 modulo 999.

Answer (score 2):

We have $$6789\sum_{r=0}^{74}10^{4r}$$

But $\displaystyle 10^1\equiv10,10^2\equiv100,10^3\equiv1\pmod{999}$

$$\implies \sum_{r=0}^{74}10^{4r}=\sum_{r=0}^{24}(1+10+100)\pmod{999}\equiv25(111)$$

We need to find $6789\cdot25\cdot111\pmod{999}$

$\displaystyle25\equiv-2,6789\equiv3\pmod9\implies25\cdot6789\equiv-2(3)\equiv-6\equiv3\pmod9$

$\implies6789\cdot25\cdot111\equiv3(111)\pmod{9(111)}$

Answer (score 1):

Answer:  If you do not know how to use modular arithmetic, here is an interesting observation:

Remainder of 6789/999 = 795

Remainder of 67890000/999 = 957

Remainder of 678900000000/999 = 579

This repeats itself for every addition of 10000.

300 digits/(3*4) = 25

Sum of the remainders = 25*(795+957+579) = 58275

Remainder of 58275/999 = 333.

Two other solutions are elegant, but this is just to add flavor.

Goodluck.

Satish